# node.js async call fails when options returned by another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, response

I've some trouble with my code in node.js

I've a Ajax call in a async function. When I make the call with options I specified in front of the call in an const then the program runs well.

But when I call an function for the options which is defined in another script then the call run's in an error.

Why this happens?

//edit//

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const logger = require('../../../libs/log');
const kasMock = require('../../mock/kasMock')
const remote = require('./remote')
var proxyUrl = "***"
var endstelle = ""
const queryCount = ""
var ticket = ""
const auth = {"api": {username: 'api', password: '***'}, "jira":{username: '***', password: '***}}
var result = {}
var uri = {}
var method = {"put":"PUT", "get":"GET"} 
/** Get all tickets */
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.send("Test")
})
app.get('/startDiagnosis', function (req, res) {
    //res.send('starte Diagnose')
    var param = req.query
    ticket = param.ticket
    endstelle = param.endstelle
     resultKas = pullKAS(endstelle)
     uri = {"jiraGetProperties":'***/rest/api/2/issue/' + ticket + '/properties/', "jiraSetProperty": '***/rest/api/2/issue/' + ticket + '/properties/kas-', "kasGetResult":'http://*** + '?_format=json'}
      resultKas = pullKAS(endstelle)
      let queryCount = jiraGetQueryCount(param.ticket,res)
      logger.info("Querycount: " + queryCount)
      queryCount.then(function(result){
        updateDiagnoseIntern(getResultData(resultKas), param.ticket,result+1)
      });
  })
async function jiraGetQueryCount(ticket,res) {
     //With the commented options the code works fine.
     //But when I call the remote.ajaxCallOptions an error    occurs.
     /*const options = {
        method: method.get
        ,rejectUnauthorized: true
        ,uri: uri.jiraGetProperties
        ,auth: auth.jira};
     */
     const options = remote.ajaxCallOptions(method.get,uri.jiraGetProperties, auth.jira);
     try {

        response = await request(options);
        res.send(response)
        let count = getQueryCount(response)
        logger.info('Get Info: ' + count);
      return(count)
      }
      catch (error) {
        logger.info("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten")
        return("error")
      }
}
```

In remote.js the options are define:

```
module.exports = {
    ajaxCallOptionsBody: function(method,uri, auth={}, body={}){
                        return {    
                                method: method
                                ,rejectUnauthorized: true
                                ,json: true
                                ,uri:uri
                                ,auth: auth
                                ,body: body
                        }}
 ,ajaxCallOptions: function(method,uri, auth={}){
        return {    
                method: method
                ,rejectUnauthorized: true
                ,json: true
                ,uri:uri
                ,auth: auth
        }
}};
```

The Console output:

```
{"message":"Server started on port: 8181","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-02-23T10:40:01.096Z"}
{"message":"HTTP-Request: GET /rest/example/startDiagnosis?ticket=ITSM-45620&endstelle=WELO-9001","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-02-23T10:40:03.441Z"}
{"message":"Querycount: [object Promise]","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-02-23T10:40:03.447Z"}
{"message":"Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-02-23T10:40:03.685Z"}
{"message":"Querycount in Diagnose: error1","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-02-23T10:40:03.687Z"}
{"message":"Update Ticket successfully:","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-02-23T10:40:03.689Z"}
{"message":"HTTP-Response: 200, runtime: 249ms","level":"info","timestamp":"2019-02-23T10:40:03.691Z"}
```

Is there an timing problem?

Thx

Felix

Comment: Hi Felix, I understand you are using npm request package, and that package by default just work using callback, not promises not async/await. Reading the documentation, you can try to promisify the request methods installing request-promise: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: What is `request`, does it return a promise?

Comment: Yes request return a promise.

Edit my code below. When I set option which is defined in /* */ then I can use the count in the promise. But when I use my function I get an error.

Comment: I use node.js with request-promise.

Comment: Can you add the output of the `error` to the question?

Comment: The error is SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"
But the son variable for auth is the same as in defined in the locally option.